# Compiling into an array in array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bring some data and save them into a single column in SQL.

I am a beginner and I thought this and that in order to achieve that.

I came up with array in array.

However, this is the limit where I could come.

[HTML Code]

```
<tbody> <!-- I think maybe I should be $scope.project_data.project_participants here in ng-model format?-->
<tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected"/>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1">
        <ui-select ng-model = "personalDetail.phase.selected" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.data_project_phase_title}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="phase in phases | filter: $select.search">
                <div ng-bind-html="phase.data_project_phase_title | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                <small ng-bind-html="phase.data_project_phase_explanation | highlight: $select.search"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ui-select ng-model="personalDetail.member.selected" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.member_name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="member in members | filter: $select.search">
                <div ng-bind-html="member.member_name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                <small ng-bind-html="member.member_email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>    
        </ui-select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker" type="text" ng-model="personalDetail.daterange" required/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Detailed Info" ng-model="personalDetail.task_description" required>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Controller.js]

```
$scope.personalDetails = [{}];
    $scope.addNew = function(personalDetail){
        $scope.personalDetails.push({ 
            'phase': "", 
            'member': "",
            'daterange': "",
            'task_description': ""
        });
    };


$http.post("../crud/projects_update.php",{
    project_participants : $scope.project_data.project_participants // This should be received from [HTML Code] but, I don't know how.
})
```

I am trying to put the HTML Code's data into

**$scope.project_data.project_participants**

but, I am lost where to put it in the HTML Code.

My final GOAL is to put *personalDetails* in a single array (I guess it is like array assoc?) and I am trying to save all in a single column in SQL.

I hope I made this clear... Sorry I am new to coding and I am lost where to go from here. Please advise me what I should do to solve this issue.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!!!

Comment: you know that storing multiple data in a column in a database is one of the biggest design error you can do? It will be very difficult to look for a specific value that is inside that field and to mantain, update the data. My advice is to review your db structure and to use a 1to1 relation between info and fields

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will try to re-design the structure.